Does hacker rank evaluate code for speed?
I am practicing on hacker rank on the following question:

Jesse loves cookies and wants the sweetness of some cookies to be
greater than value . To do this, two cookies with the least sweetness
are repeatedly mixed. This creates a special combined cookie with:
sweetness  Least sweet cookie   2nd least sweet cookie).
This occurs until all the cookies have a sweetness .
Given the sweetness of a number of cookies, determine the minimum
number of operations required. If it is not possible, return .
Example
The smallest values are . Remove them then return  to the array. Now .
Remove  and return  to the array. Now . Remove , return  and .
Finally, remove  and return  to . Now . All values are  so the process
stops after  iterations. Return .
Function Description Complete the cookies function in the editor
below.
cookies has the following parameters:
int k: the threshold value int A[n]: an array of sweetness values
Returns
int: the number of iterations required or -1

I wrote this very simple solution in Python:
def cookies(k, A):
    i = 0
    while True:
        A.sort()
        print(A)
        if A[0] >= k:
            break
        elif len(A)< 2:
            i = -1
            break
        n1 = A.pop(0)
        n2 = A.pop(0)
        new_cookie = (n1 + 2*n2)
        A.insert(0, new_cookie)
        i += 1
    return i

It fails several test cases. I don't see any errors on edge cases. Are things like speed evaluated by hacker rank? Is this not performant/optimal? Are there edge cases where my sort is causing an overflow?

Coding challenge sites often have problems where the naive implementation has poor time complexity. They'll throw very large inputs at it, and fail it if you exceed a time limit. You need to come up with clever solutions that avoid exponential complexity.

There seems to be some words missing from your copy of the HR question. Like "If it is not possible, return ." -- what is it supposed to return?

Instead of sorting the list every time through the loop, you can use binary search to insert the new cookie in the appropriate place. Sorting is n*logn, binary search is logn.

You can use heapq to solve this problem. Your current approach is inefficient and it fails as commented.
import heapq

def cookies(k, A):
    heapq.heapify(A)
    i = 0

    while len(A) > 1 and A[0] < k:
        n1 = heapq.heappop(A)
        n2 = heapq.heappop(A)
        new_cookie = n1 + 2 * n2
        heapq.heappush(A, new_cookie)
        i += 1

    if A[0] < k:
        return -1
    return i

print(cookies(7, [1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 12]))


Prints
2

Note

pop(0) from a list has an O(N) time complexity.
insert(0, value) into a list is also O(N) time complexity.

